# File-copy using Java NIO is slow on Linux

Tags: java, performance, copy, nio

I want to copy large files from my local machine to a Samba-Server (in the same GBit-LAN). When using my native File-Manager (Nemo on Ubuntu) the file is copied at ~45 MB/s. But when using Java the speed is always lower than 8 MB/s.

Here is my example code that uses Java's preferred Files.copy-method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path src = Paths.get(args[0]);
    Path dst = Paths.get(args[1]);
    System.out.println("Copy   " + src);
    System.out.println("To     " + dst);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Files.copy(src, dst);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    double took = end - start;
    took /= 1000;
    System.out.println("Speed: " + getReadableSpeed(((double) src.toFile().length()) / took, 2) + "\n");
}
```

And here is the ouput:

```
Local To Local
Copy   /media/files/bigfile.avi
To     /media/files/bigfile.avi.bak
Speed: 68 MB/s

Local To NAS
Copy   /media/files/bigfile.avi
To     /home/biggie/.gvfs/nas/backup/bigfile.avi
Speed: 7,7 MB/s
```

When copying files from the local machine back to the local machine the speed is fine. However when the target is the NAS the speed slows down drastically (using both OpenJDK 7 and Oracles JDK 7).

On Windows I get better speed:

```
Local To NAS
Copy   Z:\files\bigfile.avi
To     Y:\backup\bigfile.avi
Speed: 37 MB/s
```

Do you have any ideas why the file-transfer on Linux using Java is slow?
Or better: Do you have a solution for this? :-)

A workaround may be to call native "cp" or "rsync --progress" from Java. But I would prefer a Java-only way :-)

PS: Copying manually by reading from a FileInputStream and writing to a FileOutputStream is slow, too (< 8MB/s). ;-)

Comment: And what is the speed on the linux box if you take java out of the equation entirely? I highly suspect this is not anything related to Java specifically; SMB sucks.

Comment: As metioned above: OpenJDK and Oracles JDK 7. Or more precisely "OpenJDK 64-Bit 1.7.0_21" and "Oracles JDK 64-Bit 1.7.0_25"

Comment: Ok, maybe you're right. I tested it using rsync and dd and both get speed < 8 MB/s. However my file manager, Nemo, transfers with a speed of 45 MB/s o0

Comment: Maybe the buffer used is so small the actual read/write happens too often to be fast.

Comment: Java will be accessing the SMB share via a regular file system mount.  It is possible that Nemo is accessing SMB a different way that is faster / better tuned.

Answer (score 1):

Java will be accessing the SMB share via a regular file system mount.  It is possible that Nemo is accessing the SMB share via a different mechanism that is faster / better tuned.

Either way, if file transfer speed is critical, you will most likely get best results using an external application.  (Exactly which one will be OS specific ... and beyond the scope of StackOverflow.)

---

I had a brief look at how `Files.copy` is implemented.  It appears that the actual file copying is implemented by a native code method (`sun.nio.fs.UnixFileCopy.transfer(...)`).  Based on that, I don't think that a utility that copied a large file (via a regular file system mount) *should* go significantly faster than `Files.copy(...)`.  It would need to access it a different way to achieve a significant speedup.